# Add formatted text box to a form and save to a MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, textbox

I need to add a text box to a form with facility to format text (like bold/ italic, add tables and so on) to my web page (PHP). And I want to save it to a MYSQL database as it is. So later if I load the page, the text should be there with the formatting. How can I achieve this? Or is there any way to copy past a formatted text from MS word to a text area with formatting and save in a database?

[image: This is a similar text area]

Comment: You  can use ck editor

Comment: @YasinPatel - Thank you. So will the formatting can be saved in MYSQL database?

Comment: Yes, according to your requirement, your can take column as TEXT or LONGTEXT

Answer (score 0):

> Lot of plugins,libraries available in google check it

1. [CK EDITOR](https://ckeditor.com/)
2. [Tiny MCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/)
3. [wysiwyg-editor](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/)

Comment: @Boomainathan -  Thank you. So will the formatting can be saved in MYSQL database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like

- CK EDITOR
- SUMMERNOTE

These text box provides formatting text and saved into database as HTML format.